# Delete special characters using linux or python

Tags: linux, postgresql, csv, unicode, character-encoding

I am copying a csv file of the following form into postgres:

```
 0   "the"
 1   "parative Philosophy 62 June 2007 pp 125130 More on Jonas and Process Philosophy in The Legacy of Hans Jonas Judaism and the Phenomenon of Life Edited by Havakp TiroschSamuelson"
```

When copying this csv file into postgres I am getting the following error:

```
copy dict from '/home/r.csv' with delimiter E'\t';
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
```

I tried to remove the special characters using "sed s/\/\g' ./r.csv ". However, the special characters are not getting deleted. Is there some way that I may delete the special characters using linux or python

My operating system is ubuntu 12.04 lts.

Comment: blindly deleting parts of your data is rarely a good idea.  why do you have a null byte in your csv in the first place?

Comment: @Eevee..this is my company's dump which they have given to me

Comment: how is this related to sed and python?

Comment: @alko sed works well when replacing certain text...and i want to retain all the characters apart from special characters..therefore i thought sed /pythons regex may work

Comment: If you want us to guess how to file your input file, can you post the file somewhere, or give us a hex dump of the first 160 bytes or so here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm willing to bet the problem is that the file is actually UTF-16-LE, not UTF-8.

A string of ASCII characters like `"abc"`, when encoded as UTF-16-LE then decoded as UTF-8, will look like `"a\0b\0c\0"`, causing exactly this kind of error.

But the solution is not to strip out the `\0` nul bytes. That will *appear* to work as long as your data are all ASCII (or all ASCII plus a certain subset of Latin-1), but it will give you either garbage or errors as soon as it's anything else. For example, the CJK character U+5000 (`'倀'`) encoded as UTF-16-LE then decoded as UTF-8 looks like `'\0P'`, and you certainly don't want to strip out the nul byte and turn that into `'P'`. (For that matter, you don't want to interpret U+5050, `'偐'`, as `'PP'`.)

The right thing to do is to recode the file. For example:

```
iconv -f UTF-16-LE -t UTF-8 r.csv >r8.csv
```

Not every installation of `iconv` supports the same names, and I don't know which of the names are the canonical ones. `iconv --list |grep -i utf` should give you a list of names, and it should be obvious which one(s) mean UTF-16-LE and which UTF-8, so you can pick the appropriate one.

Of course not every system comes with `iconv`; you may need to use a different tool instead. If worst comes to worst, you can always write one in a few lines of Python.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. But i am afraid its giving me...iconv: conversion from `utf-16-le' is not supported
Try `iconv --help' or `iconv --usage' for more information.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.04. Also is there any way by which I may view the encoding of the file

Comment: Did you try `iconv --help`? It will tell you that to get a list of encodings your copy of `iconv` supports, you use `iconv --list`. It should be obvious which one(s) of those are names for UTF-16-LE and UTF-8. (If it isn't, `iconv --list |grep -i UTF` should narrow it down until it is.)

Comment: @AliceEverett: The whole problem with text files is that the encoding isn't stored _anywhere_, except in the brain of the user, or maybe the source code of the software, that created it. So, you can only view the encoding of the file by going up to the person who gave you the dump and kicking him until he remembers how he created it. Which is probably a better idea than guessing, but it doesn't always work, in which case… guessing is all you can do.

Comment: When I run this command it gives a bunch of special characters of the form"湥祣汣灯摥慩攠瑮祲椠⁮流牥捩湡倠楨潬潳桰⁹湁䔠据捹潬数楤⁡摅瑩摥戠⁹潊湨䰠捡獨愠摮删扯牥⁴慔楬獳⁥敎⁷潙歲丠⁙潒瑵敬杤⁥〲㠰瀠⁰㔳㌸〶删扯牥⁴畃浭湩獧丠癥汩敬䄠瑵扯潩牧灡票愠⁮湥祣汣灯摥慩攠瑮祲椠⁮流牥捩湡倠楨潬潳桰⁹湁䔠据捹潬数楤⁡摅瑩摥戠⁹潊湨䰠捡獨愠摮删扯牥⁴慔楬獳⁥敎⁷潙歲丠⁙潒瑵敬杤⁥〲㠰瀠⁰㐵㔴㔴倠慬潴楮浳䤠普畬湥散漠⁦湡攠据捹潬数楤⁡湥牴⁹湩䄠敭楲慣⁮桐汩獯灯票䄠⁮湅祣汣灯摥慩䔠楤整⁤祢䨠桯⁮慌档⁳湡⁤潒敢瑲吠污獩敳丠睥夠牯⁫奎删畯汴摥敧㈠〰‸灰㔠〹㤵″慐汵圠楥獳愠⁮湥祣汣灯摥慩攠瑮祲椠⁮流牥捩湡倠楨潬潳桰⁹湁䔠据捹潬数楤⁡摅瑩摥戠⁹潊湨䰠捡獨愠摮删扯牥⁴慔楬獳⁥敎⁷潙歲丠⁙潒瑵敬杤⁥〲㠰瀠⁰〸㠰㈰䄠䌠浯慰楲潳⁮景䌠湯畦楣湡愠摮䌠牨獩楴湡䌠湯散瑰潩獮漠⁦牃慥楴楶祴椠⁮慄⁯⁡潊牵慮⁬景䌠浯慰慲楴敶倠楨潬潳桰⁹㈶䨠湵⁥〲㜰瀠⁰㈱ㄵ〳䴠牯⁥湯䨠湯獡愠摮倠潲散獳倠楨潬潳桰⁹湩吠敨䰠来捡⁹景䠠湡⁳潊慮⁳畊慤獩⁭湡⁤桴⁥桐湥浯湥湯漠⁦楌敦䔠楤整⁤祢䠠癡aĀ火 楔潲捳卨浡敵獬湯愠摮䌠楨瑳慩⁮楗獥⁥敌摩湥䈠楲汬㈠〰‸灰㔠ㄱㄵ‸桃湥⁧桃湵祧湩獧䌠湯瑳畲瑣癩⁥桐汩獯灯票椠⁮桔⁥浉数慲"

Comment: @AliceEverett: That's a plausible output of interpreting UTF-16-BE as UTF-16-LE. So maybe try converting from BE instead of LE. Meanwhile, there are tools that can help you guess, like [`chardet`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet). I don't know of any such tools that come with Ubuntu, but you can always install one. Still not as good as recognizing the bytes, or kicking your coworker until he remembers, but it may be helpful.

Comment: I coverted from be instead of le...its still giving me 慮⁐桩汯獯灨礠䅮⁅湣祣汯灥摩愠䕤楴敤⁢礠䩯桮⁌慣桳⁡湤⁒潢敲琠呡汩獳攠乥眠奯牫⁎夠副畴汥摧攠㈰〸⁰瀠㌵㠳㘰⁒潢敲琠䍵浭楮杳⁎敶楬汥⁁畴潢楯杲慰桹⁡渠敮捹捬潰敤楡⁥湴特⁩渠䅭敲楣慮⁐桩汯獯灨礠䅮⁅湣祣汯灥摩愠䕤楴敤⁢礠䩯桮⁌慣桳⁡湤⁒潢敲琠呡汩獳攠乥眠奯牫⁎夠副畴汥摧攠㈰〸⁰瀠㔴㐵㐵⁐污瑯湩獭⁉湦汵敮捥⁯映慮⁥湣祣汯灥摩愠敮瑲礠楮⁁浥物捡渠偨楬潳潰桹⁁渠䕮捹捬潰敤楡⁅摩瑥搠批⁊潨渠䱡捨猠慮搠副扥牴⁔慬楳獥⁎敷⁙潲欠乙⁒潵瑬敤来′〰㠠灰‵㤰㔹㌠偡畬⁗

Comment: @AliceEverett: OK, so that guess was wrong. We can keep trying to guess what's wrong with your file if you want, but have you ruled out asking the person who gave it to you?

Comment: Yes I have ruled out asking the person..as he has left comapny :(

Comment: Actually I just want to retain alphabets and numbers and characters which are present in a wesite's URL,..the rest i can discard..is it possible to find way using this

Comment: @dstromberg: I already mentioned chardet a couple comments ago. Are you trying to add something, or just repeating it?

Comment: I didn't see it before adding it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to figure out where these nul bytes came from, and would rather just get rid of them and cross your fingers:

I don't believe there's anything in either GNU sed or BSD sed that lets you specify any special characters besides `\n` for newline. There are lots of ways to get a literal nul byte into the argument to `sed`… but I'll bet `sed` will just treat that as the end of the string anyway.

Rather than fighting with `sed`, let's do it in Python. No need for regexps, just plain `str.replace`. If the file is small enough that it's no problem to read it into memory:

```
with open('r.csv', 'rb') as fin, open('r2.csv', 'wb') as fout:
    fout.write(fin.read().replace('\0', ''))
```

… if it's too big for that, but it's close enough to valid ASCII that it makes sense to think of it as lines:

```
with open('r.csv', 'rb') as fin, open('r2.csv', 'wb') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(line.replace('\0', ''))
```

Comment: I am afraid but still those characters are present. I wanted to copy and show thm..but i dont know why are they not getting copied

Comment: @AliceEverett: Are you sure they're still present in the new `r2.csv` file, and it's not just that you're using the old `r.csv` file instead?